# How to extend S3 method from another package without loading the package

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I am developing a package which has the function `forecast.myclass`. I want that function to work nicely with `forecast` package. I.e. when `forecast` package is loaded the code `forecast(object)` should call `forecast.myclass` from my package.

Since I need only generic definition of `forecast` from the package `forecast`, and I do not use any other function from the package `forecast` I am reluctant to include it in the Depends. So I define the generic in my package in the following way:

```
##'
##' @export
forecast <- function(object,...) UseMethod("forecast") 

##' @rdname forecast.midas_r
##' @method forecast midas_r
##' @export
forecast.midas_r <- function(object,newdata=NULL,method=c("static","dynamic"),insample=get_estimation_sample(object),...) {
```

Now everything works as expected when package `forecast` is not loaded. But when I load package `forecast`, then `forecast.midas_r` is not called, when doing `forecast(object)` where `object` is of class `midas_r`.  How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Unless you are documenting `forecast.midas_r` (which you are not), you only need `@S3method(forcast, midas_r)` - that will not create an Rd file, but will add the correct line to the NAMESPACE (which is the first place to look if you're having problems)

Comment: @hadley I document the forecast.midas_r in a way that forecast and forecast.midas_r share the same help page. The code is here: https://github.com/mpiktas/midasr/blob/master/R/midas_r_methods.R, starts at line 279

Comment: This post is quite old with no accepted solution, so I comment here for reference, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079179/does-using-package-generics-require-the-package-to-be-in-depends-or-imports seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure there's an easy solution to this. As others have said it's probably easiest to use `Depends` to get around this, rather than redefining a generic method.

Here's a simple example which works for me. It's largely the same as your solution, but declaring `@export` means you won't need to manually update the `NAMESPACE` file.

```
##' @name mean
##' @export mean.newClass
##' 
##' @method mean newClass
##'
##' @title mean for \code{newClass} object
##' @param x A \code{newClass} object
##' @param ... Additional arguments
##'
mean.newClass <- function(x, ...){
  stopifnot(class(x)=="newClass")
  return(42)
}
```

Then `package.skeleton("newPkg")`. Put file `mean.R` with the above contents in the directory `/R` of the package.

Ensure you're in the directory 1 level below, then

```
roxygenize("newPkg", roxygen.dir="newPkg", copy.package=F, unlink.target=F)
```

Now

```
library(devtools)
dev_mode(on=TRUE) ### don't want to have to uninstall the package later
install_local("newPkg")
library(newPkg)
x <- c(1,2)
class(x) <- "newClass"
stopifnot(mean(x)==42)
stopifnot(mean(unclass(x))==1.5)
```

I realize `mean` is a function in `base` but I have tested this for modifying generic functions elsewhere to give them a new method, so it should extend to your more general case also.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that your definition of the `forecast` generic is masking the definition from the forecast package, and your method is associated with your generic rather than the forecast package generic; this is just a complicated instance of two packages defining functions of the same name. The solution is to bite the bullet and Depend: on forecast, or when at the command line and both your package and forecast are attached fully resolve the function `mypackage::forecast()`, or Import: forecast but not make the forecast generic available to the end user except by having them `require(forecast)` (this might be appropriate if `forecast` functionality were somehow peripheral to your package, e.g., plotting in 3D when plotting in 2D was sufficient).

For what it's worth, an S4 method in PkgB defined and exported on an imported S4 generic from PkgA implicitly exposes the S4 generic to the user, so the generic is available even if Imports: PkgA is specified in the DESCRIPTION file of PkgB.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to forcefully export forecast.midas_r. This means manually updating `NAMESPACE` with `export(forecast.midas_r)` everytime after `check("yourpackagename")`.

What this does is make `forecast.midas_r` visible for package *forecast*. If `forecast.midas_r` is not exported, and exists only in the namespace of the package, then when package *forecast* is loaded, the generic `forecast` is overwritten with the identical function from package *forecast*. So when `forecast` is invoked on unknown object, R looks up for corresponding methods in package *forecast* and in general workspace. Since `forecast.midas_r` is a private method R does not find it and produces an error.

This is not a perfect solution, since you need to manually update `NAMESPACE`, but it is a solution nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

[This github issue](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1915) was very helpful for me.

Following the patterns of {sf}:

1. Don't export your functions in your namespace
2. Copy the [register_s3_method() function definition](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/r-spatial/sf/main/R/tidyverse.R) in a new R script or the same that has your methods
3. copy the scaffolding for registering all methods and repeat the body for all of the methods you may have in your package

```r
register_all_s3_methods = function() {
  register_s3_method("pkg", "function", "class")
}
```

4. In a new R script (preferably `zzz.R`), have an `.onLoad()` hook containing

```r
.onLoad = function(libname, pkgname) {
  register_all_s3_methods()
}
```

5. Redocument your package
6. devtools::load_all()