# Does using package generics require the package to be in Depends or Imports?

Tags: r

First of all, I have read around this topic a lot. I have studied the conversations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637993/better-explanation-of-when-to-use-imports-depends), [here](http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/), [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) and [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/). The problem is, however, I still think one particular topic isn't discussed fully. I am developing a package and I wish to create my own method using the `autoplot()` generic from the `ggplot2` package, i.e. have a function such as `autoplot.MyFunction()`.

My current `DESCRIPTION` file contains `Depends: ggplot2` and everything works, no problem. I also combine this with Roxygen2 tags `@import ggplot2` within my function's help file code, coupled with `@export`.

However most documentation describes how one should try to use `Imports: ggplot2`. The trouble is, if I make this change, when I load my package with `library(my_package)` and try to use `autoplot.MyFunction()`, I am faced with the following error:

```
> autoplot(tmp)
Error: could not find function "autoplot"
```

Similarly, if I call the function directly...

```
> autoplot.MyFunction(tmp)
Error: could not find function "autoplot.MyFunction"
```

However if I use the `::` method, then it does work...

```
> ggplot2::autoplot(tmp)
```

From my understanding, this is because `Imports` *loads* the `ggplot2` package (and therefore its functions), but doesn't *attach* it, whereas `Depends` does *attach* it.

So, finally, my question is simple, am I correct in thinking that to use package generics, I should be using `Depends: package`, i.e. in my case `Depends: ggplot2`.

Then for using functions from packages within my package functions I should be using `Imports: package` coupled with `::`, e.g.:

```
silly_fn <- function (data) {
  p <- ggplot(tmp, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 20, y = 0, yend = 20), 
                 arrow = grid::arrow(length = grid::unit(0.15, "inches")))
  p
}
```

would require `Imports: grid` and a Roxygen2 tag `@import grid`.

I think this is all correct?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a complete expert on this, but here is something that works:

```
#' @importFrom ggplot2 autoplot
#' @export autoplot

autoplot <- autoplot

#' @export "autoplot.foo"

autoplot.foo <- function(obj, ...) {
  cat("bar\n")
}
```

Unfortunately we need to explicitly export the method because for some reason S3 dispatch from a package namespace (in this case `ggplot2`) doesn't find the method registered from a package it doesn't import from.  This kind of makes sense except that it works for base generics so there is a subtlety of the S3 registration mechanism that I'm not privy to.

Re whether to use `::` within your package or not, it's up for debate.  You don't have to if you use `@import` or `@importFrom`, but some (including Hadley) suggest you should for clarity.  I personally recommend against it because the R profiler doesn't resolve function names of the style `package::method`, which makes it harder to optimize code (there are workarounds that can meet both objectives).

Note you should absolutely use `@import` and not rely solely on `::` (you will also have to update the `DESCRIPTION` file).  Failing to do so will prevent R from being aware of the dependency.  I'm pretty sure `R CMD check` yells about this.

Comment: Addendum: another important reason to use `@import` is that it forces a load-time (rather than run-time) dependency. This can be important if the imported package has an `.onLoad()` hook which must be executed up front.