# Creating a method for an S3 generic from another package (autoplot in ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I do not seem to fully understand how to add a method to a generic function from another package, in an R package that I am currently developing.

I am now trying to make a method `autoplot.myobj` for the `autoplot` generic defined in `ggplot2`, without adding `ggplot2` to DEPENDS.

For this line in NAMESPACE: `S3method(autoplot,emfrail)`, R CMD build fails with

> Error: autoplot not found whilst loading namespace

Then, If I also add `importFrom(ggplot2, autoplot)`, R CMD build works, but R CMD check returns

> Error: could not find function autoplot

So I understand that a generic imported from another package must also be exported. Then, if I also add `export(autoplot)`, R CMD build works, R CMD check gives

> Warning: undocumented code objects

This means that I also have to document `autoplot`, although it is already documented in `ggplot2`. Then I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079179/does-using-package-generics-require-the-package-to-be-in-depends-or-imports) and I also have in the NAMESPACE `export(autoplot.emfrail)` in addition to all the previous ones.

Then I added an `@rdname autoplot.emfrail` roxygen tag to the documentation. Then R CMD build and R CMD check work both. The disadvantage that I see is that with `?autoplot` now, the function is documented in both `ggplot2` and my package.

Is this the best way to make an S3 method for a generic from another package?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513607/how-to-extend-s3-method-from-another-package-without-loading-the-package

Comment: When I re-exported a function with `roxygen`, a help file called `reexports` was automagically created, which includes links to the original documentation.