# Expanding the basic methods for a R class and how to document with roxygen2?

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I want to create a class of results, say `things`. The main function `makeThings` returns (actually a list) with the class `things` addded (all these details are given in code below).

In addition to the method `print`, which should be the default method to display things, I want another method called `explain` which would print things with more information.

How can I create the second method, and make sure that it is sent to NAMESPACE using roxygen tags as this is to be put in a CRAN-compatible package. I believe S3 object-oriented approach is fine for my purpose.

A MWE:

```
#' @title makeThings is the main function
#' 
#' @description
#' This is what this function does.
#' 
#' @export
makeThings <- function(x) {
    res <- list(A=1:10, B=40:50)
    class(res) <- "things"
    return(res) 
}

#' @title print is the default method for things
#' 
#' @description
#' print outputs using a very basic format
#' 
#' @export
print.things <- function( something, ...) {print(something$A)}

#' @title explain is another, more verbosed, method for showing things.
#' 
#' @description
#' use explain( makeThings(43) ) to have more details.
#' 
#' @method explain things
#' @export
explain.things <- function( something, ...) {print("The meaning is ...")}
```

Now, as it stands, `print` and `explain` are sent as S3method to NAMESPACE, but typing `? explain` indicates that explain is in the generic environment, not in my package environment. Also, typing the instruction

```
explain(makeThings(3))
```

returns the error `Error in explain(makeThings(3)) : could not find function "explain"`. Some explanations appreciated as I tried many variations with no luck so far.

As far as possible, I would like to have these three functions in the same file.

Comment: 1) To get help you need the full name: `?explain.things`; 2) have you [exported the methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512528/how-to-export-s3-method-so-it-is-available-in-namespace)?

Comment: There is a standard generic function `print`, but there's no standard function `explain`.  You would need to create that yourself; see the examples in section 5.1 of the R Language Definition manual.

Comment: @RuiBarradas:  it has nothing to do with the question, so I'll edit it out.

Comment: @RuiBarradas so based on the link, I would have to both ``@export explain.things`` and ``@export``? Yes, that and the next comments both seems to do the trick.

Comment: @user2554330 from section 5.1, I get that I must add ``explain <- function(x, ...) {  UseMethod("explain") }`` so that I have a routing function? Does seems to work. Anyone wants to turn this into a response?

Comment: I know what you should put in your `.R` code and in the `NAMESPACE`, but your question appears to be about doing this via `Roxygen2`, which I don't use (or recommend except in very limited circumstances), so it will have to be someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have objects of a new class and have those objects processed by methods of generic functions.
To create a new generic you have to use `UseMethod` and it's a good idea to create a default method.

```r
#' @title makeThings is the main function
#' 
#' @description
#' This is what this function does.
#' 
#' @export
makeThings <- function(x) {
  res <- list(A = 1:10, B = 40:50)
  class(res) <- "things"
  return(res) 
}

#' @title explain is another, more verbosed, method for showing things.
#' 
#' @description
#' use explain( makeThings(43) ) to have more details.
#' 
#' @details
#' This is the generic function
explain <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("explain")

#' @method explain default
#' @export
explain.default <- function(x, ...) print(x)

#' @method explain things
#' @export
explain.things <- function(x, ...) {print("The meaning is ...")}

#' @examples
explain("Hello, world!")
#> [1] "Hello, world!"
explain(makeThings(3))
#> [1] "The meaning is ..."
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Then these functions should be exported from the package's namespace.
roxigen will write the following in the file `NAMESPACE` And with a message saying not to edit by hand.

```
S3method(explain, things)
export(explain)
export(makeThings)
```