# How to specify that a function will NOT use default namespace (S3)? roxygen2?

Tags: r, plot, methods, roxygen2

I have created a function `plot.tukey` that builds a custom graphic using the `base` plotting tools, overlaying multiple `plot` calls with `par(new=TRUE)`.

When I documented with `roxygen2`, it added an `S3method` wrapper on the function to `NAMESPACE`

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

S3method(plot,tukey)


export(color.randomHEX)
```

### Question 1:  Do I *always* want such an automatic wrapper?

What are the advantages / disadvantages of inheriting `methods("plot")`?

### Question 2:  If I choose to *NOT* want this function to be tied to the `S3method`, how do I tell `roxygen2`?

Why did `roxygen2` assume I wanted this function attached to `S3`?  Only based on the name of the function?  Regardless, how do I tell `roxygen2` to export AS-IS, without `S3` as it did with the function `color.randomHEX`?

Comment: If you name your function `plot.tukey` that's the convention that S3 uses. If you don't want S3, to avoid cofunction, it would be better to use something like `plot_tukey` as the name of the function. But you can export both an S3 version and the full function by adding a second export. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512528/how-to-export-s3-method-so-it-is-available-in-namespace

Comment: @MrFlick How to use `plot.tukey` but tell R, "I don't want to be part of the `methods('plot')` namespace?"  How to `delist` from the namespace?

Comment: I think you just need to use `@export plot.tukey` but you didn't provide a reproducible example so I can't easily test. This is really an `roxygen` thing because it tried very hard to do the "right" thing based on your function names. If you manually edited your NAMESPACE file you could put whatever you want in there.

Comment: https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/243 says be explicit with `@export`.  In the above example, I just used `@export` *NOT* `@export plot.tukey` ...